# mediaplayer : artist and displaying

Tags: android, cursor

Query the android Mediastore for Artist names of songs from sdcard.If we click the artist it will display all the songs of particular artist.I tried like that but it display all the songs in the sdcard.thanks in advance.

```
  private void music_grid(int ch) {
    System.gc();
    String[] musicproj ={MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID,
                         MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST, 
                     MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_ALBUMS,
                     MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS}

         final String sortOrder = ArtistColumns.ARTIST
                    + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        musiccursor = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    musicproj, null, null, null);

            count = musiccursor.getCount();
            gridmusic = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridmusic);
            Madapter = new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            gridmusic.setAdapter(Madapter);
            gridmusic.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener1);

        }
```